# Oracle View vs joining tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, view

I understand that a view is a window to an underlying table or set of tables in Oracle. For instance if I have a view that is created by joining multiple tables , will the view perform the actual join operations when I select data from the view? Does a view perform better than joining multiple tables to fetch data or is it the same with respect to performance?

Comment: Look at the execution plan for both to know: but I believe the view wuld be slower if filtering criteria is applied.  (assuming we're not talking about a materialized view)  I think the view must materialize first and then the limits applied, where as if selecting from tables directly, the engine can optimize the joins and filter out data based on critiera and indexes; which the view ***may*** not be able to do.

Comment: Thanks xQbert , yes I was talking about views. I assume materialized views with use additional storage space.

Comment: Thanks xQbert , What does "materialize first" mean?

Comment: What I mean is that the results of the table joins must first be brought into memory and then the limits are applied.  This means that more data may be brought into memory than needed if the engine had been able to optimize the query before bringing in the results. So If I had two tables each with 10,000 rows and did a cross join I'd get a 10,000,000 result set. And then need to limit it down to the 4 records i actually needed...   However if the engine applied filters to each of those tables first to say get only 2 rows from each, I'd end up with only 4. only needed to go though 10,000 twice

Comment: Thanks again! Doesn't engine get involved when when retrieving data using views?

Comment: But views are Pre-compiled SQL statements so the engine can be faster when returning the entire data set as it doesn't have the overhead of compiling the view. However, this can be offset by the fact the engine may not be able to limit the data as effectively as it could if it was just processing against the tables directly.   So in some cases it will be faster (When selecting all data from the view) or it may be slower when selecting small subsets of the data from the view.  that's why I say Look at the execution plan for both methods  Its the only way to "KNOW" which is faster.

Comment: Thanks xQbert! Please can you post this as an answer and I'll accept. It was very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually no performance difference between a single query and a logically equivalent query that uses views.

Oracle has optimizer transformations that can combine views with the outer query; predicate pushing, simple and complex view merging, etc.  Think of views more like a text macro that builds a large query, instead of a function that returns rows.

For example, in the below query Oracle would probably be smart enough to push the predicate on the primary key column into the view.  Although the view by itself might return millions of rows, when the entire query is run Oracle will apply the predicate on the primary key column first.

```
select *
from view_returns_millions_of_rows
where primary_key_value = 1;
```