# Oracle difference between select from SQL and VIEW

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, view

I have below SQL which will be running on Oracle 11g.

Want to know is there is any difference in Executing the SQL directly or through view and any performance difference

```
select a.*, b.*, c.* 
  from TABLE_A a
  join TABLE_B b on b.id = a.id
  join TABLE_C c on c.taskid = b.taskid
 where (b.taskid  in (1,2,3)) 
    or (b.taskid  in (4,5) and a.creation_date > (sysdate-10) );
```

Comment: there is not difference in performance  ..  the view is just a "stored code"

Comment: Why not just run both the queries and see the difference by yourself.

Comment: Depends on what the view definition is; is your query in your question what the view definition would be using?  If so, @scaisEdge is right; no discernible difference. That is, if that SQL is the view definition, then invoking a query against the view, would be the same performance; you are just making programmer's life less complicated by hiding the join complexity.

Comment: Check the execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

Does below Question-Answer satisfies your curiosity, I find it quite similar:

[Oracle View vs joining tables in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314372/oracle-view-vs-joining-tables-in-oracle)